# Bitcoin vs Monero: What is better?

Tags: mymonero

I've 0.01 Bitcoin. Can I create a wallet and export my Bitcoin in my wallet? What are the changes between Bitcoin and Monero?

Comment: Too broad and unclear, I'm voting to close. Feel free to ask other, separate, questions, such as how to exchange bitcoin for monero, how to create wallets, and what are the main differences between bitcoin and monero.

Comment: Agree that this question is too broad, ambiguous, and unclear.  Are you looking got information on how to exchange Bitcoin for Monero or something else?

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily too broad to ask what are the major differences between Bitcoin and Monero, and this doesn't seem to be a question that's been asked/answered yet.

Comment: @jwinterm I agree it is too broad, but in the future maybe we should suggest edits to better word the question (giving it a more narrow focus) instead of voting to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ronrunner, you can't export Bitcoin to Monero, if that's what you're asking - you have to trade Bitcoin for Monero on an exchange, such as Poloniex or Bittrex.

There are a number of differences between Bitcoin and Monero, including:

- Monero uses ring signatures to achieve on-chain mixing of your transactions to make transactions untraceable; Bitcoin uses no mixing by default.
- Monero uses built-in stealth addresses to hide account balances and make transactions unlinkable, while Bitcoin makes account/address balances public.
- Monero uses a different hashing algorithm for proof-of-work; Bitcoin uses Sha256 while Monero uses [CryptoNight](https://cryptonote.org/cns/cns008.txt).
- Monero has an [adaptive block size limit](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=753252.msg13591241#msg13591241), while Bitcoin blocks are fixed at a maximum of 1 MB.
- Monero has a tail emission of less than 1% of the total supply per year, which will maintain some block reward into perpetuity; Bitcoin will eventually cease block rewards and reward miners with tx fees alone.

One other change that is planned to be implemented in the future is [ring confidential transactions](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1098.pdf), which is designed to further improve the privacy of the system.